# How to access WPF MainWindow Controls from my own .cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I am a NOVICE and am very much struggling with what seems should be a very simple task.  How do I modify a property of a `MainWindow` `TextBlock`, from another cs file.  An exact code solution would be extremely helpful.

Below is the stripped down code. Is my use of static class causing me extra issues?

In File: MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="107,71,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In File: MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace TestApp1  
{  
public partial class MainWindow : Window  
    {  
        public MainWindow()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
            TextBlock1.Text = "Setting Text from MainWindow";  
            MyProgram.myProgramStart();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

In File: CodeFile1.cs

```
namespace TestApp1
{
    public static class MyProgram
    {
        public static void myProgramStart()
        {
            // ... blah blah blah

            // I want to do something like follows, but won't compile
            MainWindow.TextBlock1.Text = "Setting Text from My Program";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 51):

Because nobody else has actually answered the question I'm going to tell you how to achieve what you want, but do listen to the posters who said that in a real application you would use MVVM. However there are times when you need to do what you ask so the code you need is:

```
((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).TextBlock1.Text = "Setting Text from My Program";
```

Comment: nice answer, but i just wanted to repeat in bold letters : **"but do listen to the posters who said that in a real application you would use MVVM. "**

Comment: Great answer, but in case someone really missed it... **"but do listen to the posters who said that in a real application you would use MVVM"**.

Comment: I don't get the generalization of the bonus advice at all. There are several reasons to need code-behind in that way. e.g. a custom style.xaml's code-behind using procedural code for the use of handlers in styles for methods that xaml isn't algorithmic enough for.

Comment: Sometimes the MVVM option is many lines of code to replace 1 line of "bad" code
TheStatusbar.MouseUp += ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).SBMouseUp;

Comment: @jriv This is not about code-behind. It's not even about MVVM. It's about the way the controls are referenced in your application. It's a code smell in *many* ways. MVVM is one solution out of many that gracefully avoids such a situation. Of course MVVM and code-behind are not mutual exclusive. And nobody was saying this.

Answer (score 17):

You can simply achieve this using MVVM. You shouldn't directly access controls in View using its name from another class. You have to use binding properties.

First of all, add a class. This will be your **ViewModel**. Add your properties to this class which will be binded to your input controls in your **View**.

**Student ViewModel**

```cs
public class Student
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Setting Text from My Program"; }
    }
}
```

**App.Config**

Now you have add to this View Model as a resource in your **App.Config** file. First, add the name space reference to your app.config where your VM resides.
[xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2]. Add your VM class as a resource by specifying your View Model class name (student).

```xml
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
    
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:Student x:Key="Student" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

Set the `DataContext` with the resource key added to App.config and set the binding to the property defined in the Student View Model.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{StaticResource Student}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="127,124,0,0" Name="textBlock1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Please note that if the binding source does not extend DependecyObject it *has* to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, even if the PropertyChanged event is not raised. In case the source extends DependencyObject, the properties that serve as binding source/target must be implemented as dependency properties instead. Otherwise the data binding will create a memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

**Basically there are more than 2-3 methods. Given method is quite easier to understand & handle.
You can access MainWindow controls by following codes (1),(2),(3),(4).**

In File: MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
  public partial class MainWindow
  {
   internal static MainWindow Main; //(1) Declare object as static
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Main =this; //(2) Defined Main (IMP)
      var AnyClassORWindow=new Class1(); //Initialize another Class
      AnyClassORWindow.ShowValue();
    }
  }
```

In File: Class1.cs

```
  internal class Class1 : MainWindow //(3) Inherited
    {
      internal void Display()
        {
           MessageBox.Show(Main.TextBox1.Text); //(4) Access MainWindow Controls by adding 'Main' before it.
         }
     }
```

> **Notes:-**
>
> 1. It's good practice to use code (2) after window LOADED not in CONSTRUCTOR.
> 2. Code (2) in constructor may leave run-time problems.
> 3. Another simple method is to use 'ref MainWindow_field' by passing to each class's Constructor OR assign '(MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow' to static Main.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MVVM pattern` to access properties of the control and modify them:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Setting Text from My Program"; }
    }
}
```

Set the `DataContext` of the `XAML` in the code behind:

```
this.DataContext = new Student();
```

Bind the Text property to Name:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Comment: Please note that if the binding source does not extend DependecyObject it *has* to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, even if the PropertyChanged event is not raised. In case the source extends DependencyObject, the properties that serve as binding source/target must be implemented as dependency properties instead. Otherwise the data binding will create a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `MainWindow`.

But there shouldn't be a reason to do that because it will be done automagically in an WPF app. Unless you have specific reason to do that (which I doubt because of this question and because you say you're a novice).

Answer (score 0):

As for why it won't compile, I will assume the compiler error you are getting is...

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TestApp1.MainWindow.TextBlock1'`

This happens because you are trying to access an `TextBlock1` as if it were static. As @JeffRSon stated, create an instance of your MainWindow class first.

```
// Create an instance of MainWindow
var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.TextBlock1.Text = "Setting Text from My Program";
```

I assume you may want to display the window as well...

```
mainWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on what Nathan said, I used a safe cast:

```
(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow)?.TextBlock1.Text = "Setting Text from My Program";
```

*Note the comments on the [answer Nathan gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20326804/9833095). This isn't ideal but it works.*

Answer (score 0):

you can use `App.Current.MainWindow` anywhere in your app :)

You should also use the FindChild method to find your component ...

MyProgram.cs :

```
 public static class MyProgram
    {
        public static void myProgramStart()
        {
            // ... blah blah blah

            // I want to do something like follows, but won't compile
            //MainWindow.TextBlock1.Text = "Setting Text from My Program";
            var tb = FindChild3<TextBlock>(App.Current.MainWindow, "TextBlock1");
            tb.Text = "Setting Text from My Program";
        }

        public static T FindChild3<T>(DependencyObject depObj, string childName)
            where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm obj is valid. 
            if (depObj == null) return null;

            // success case
            if (depObj is T && ((FrameworkElement)depObj).Name == childName)
                return depObj as T;

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

                //DFS
                var obj = FindChild3<T>(child, childName);

                if (obj != null)
                    return obj;
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyProgram.myProgramStart();
        }
    }
```

This trick worked for me :)

GoodLuck ✌️