# Can I access main Window ViewModel from others child windows ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

First I must apologies if this is simple. I am very new with WPF and MVVM and I want to make sure I am not violating any WPF or MVVM concept. Also, for the wordy explanation below (trying to give all details):

I am currently referencing to an Assembly dll with all the business logic or service layer (service classes, entity classes, data operations, etc).

This is used in others traditional Windows Forms applications. I am now creating a new desktop WPF application (early stage) and I must consume the same assembly.

I created a main windows with menu, status bar, etc. and its ViewModel (Lets called _mainViewModel).

I created another simple windows with its own ViewModel object (Lets called _abcViewModel). Windows objects/controls are binding fine in child view. This works great and so far I am happy with it.

The _abcViewModel consumes logic from the assembly that can retrieve some messages using traditional delegates and event handlers.

Now, my intention is to bind the messages coming from those events to the Main Window StatusBar object which is bind to _mainWindowViewModel.StatusBarItemMessage. How can I do that?

I found from another stackoverflow post (: [How to access WPF MainWindow Controls from my own .cs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001486/how-to-access-wpf-mainwindow-controls-from-my-own-cs-file)) that you can access main window objects by using something like:
 ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow)._mainWindowViewModel.StatusBarMessage = args.Message;

I subscribe those DLL events handlers within _abcViewModel:

```
    private void SubscribeBusinessLogicEvents()
    {
        _SPPIDDrawingWPFService.PidToolBoxInfoEvent += new SPPIDDrawingWPFService.PidToolBoxInfoEventHandler(PidToolBoxInfoEvent);
        _SPPIDDrawingWPFService.PidToolBoxErrorEvent += new SPPIDDrawingWPFService.PidToolBoxErrorEventHandler(PidToolBoxErrorEvent);
    }


    private void UnsubscribeBusinessLogicEvents()
    {
        _SPPIDDrawingWPFService.PidToolBoxInfoEvent -= PidToolBoxInfoEvent;
        _SPPIDDrawingWPFService.PidToolBoxErrorEvent -= PidToolBoxErrorEvent;

    }


    internal void PidToolBoxErrorEvent(object sender, PidToolBoxEventArg args)
    {
        App.WriteLocalErrorLogFile(args);
    }


    internal void PidToolBoxInfoEvent(object sender, PidToolBoxEventArg args)
    {
        //Is this correct? Can I change Main Windows view model from here?
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow)._mainWindowViewModel.StatusBarItemMessage = args.Message;
        if (args.OptionalPopUpFlag)
        {
            //
        }
        App.WriteWoodEngSysToolBoxErrorLog(args);
    }
```

Is this the correct way? Is accessing ViewModels from other ViewModels breaking the concept of Model–view–viewmodel or MVVM?.

How can I update main Window Statusbar control from operations that are executed from child windows. I do not want to end up with a massive ViewModel object for all windows.

Any help/advise would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Event Aggregation.  Your MainWindowViewmodel should subscribe to "events" that your AbcViewModel broadcasts.  This will decouple your AbcViewModel from your MainWindowViewModel.

[Prism](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/event-aggregator.html) is a library that implements this pattern.  The library may be overkill for your needs, but you can easily implement your own system.

Your usage may look like something similar:

**AbcViewModel.cs**

```
 internal void PidToolBoxInfoEvent(object sender, PidToolBoxEventArg args)
 {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<PidToolBoxUpdateEvent>().Publish(args);

        App.WriteWoodEngSysToolBoxErrorLog(args);
  }
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel(IEventAggregator ea)
    {
        // You may need to subscribe on the UI thread. 
        // If so, use: Subscribe(..., ThreadOption.UIThread) 
        ea.GetEvent<PidToolBoxUpdateEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateStatusBar);
    }

    void UpdateStatusBar(PidToolBoxEventArg pidEventArgs)
    {
        //implement logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that was quick.  Thanks so much Michael for your quick response. I am going to have a look at Prism Event Aggregation and see how it works. I am done for today, but i will have a look tomorrow and come back to you. Thanks

Comment: Hi Michael. The IEventAggregator worked for me. I had to use BackgroundWorker within the AbcViewModel which execute the GetEvent(xxx).Publish(Args). Now it is refreshing nicely. 

What I did was:
1.-Created the main IEventAggregator object in the App.xaml.cs as Static.
2.-Pass the EventAggregator object to both viewModels constructor
3.-Subscribe the assembly event handlers and execute the process within the backgroundWorker... Question. Can I just interact with static ea directly from the models instead of passing it through the constructor? Or that would be against the MVVM philosophy?

Comment: Sorry my previous comment-question is confusing. i am trying to ask whether or not i can access the static EventAggregator object (created in App.xaml.cs) from the ViewModels instead of passing it through the constructors of the ViewModels? Or that is against MVVM. Thanks Michael. really appreciated

Comment: You can provide a singleton instance via static constructor -- however, it'd be best to leverage dependency injection for testing.  Don't forget to accept this answer as answered :)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I accepted as answered. However, as I am new I do not have enough reputation to vote up the answer as useful.... Never mind... thanks very much for your help